# Value not passed for textarea in ISSET

Tags: php, textarea, isset

I pass values so that I can modify the contents of the database.

When I pass text data flows and updates correctly. But for textarea data does not flow.
The code in which I am passing is :

```
    echo '<table border=0>';
    while ($get_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($getedit))
        {
            echo '<form method="POST" action="">';

            echo '<tr><td>Sr.No:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['SRNO'].' name="SRNO" readonly="readonly"></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['fname'].' name="fname"></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['lname'].' name="lname"></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Phone No:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['phone'].' name="phone"></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>E-mail address:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['email'].' name="email"</td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Address:</td><td><textarea rows=4>'.$get_row['address'].'</textarea></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Comments:</td><td><textarea rows=4>'.$get_row['comments'].'</textarea></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="save"></td><td></td></tr>';
            echo '</form>';                                 
        }
    echo '</table>';
```

And the code where I pass it is :

```
if (empty($_POST) === false)
{

    $fname= $_POST['fname'];
    $lname= $_POST['lname'];
    $srno=  $_POST['SRNO'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $comments=$_POST['comments'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    echo 'Hello'.$address;          
    mysql_query('update names set fname="'.$fname.'", lname="'.$lname.'", address="'.$address.'", comments="'.$comments.'", email="'.$email.'", phone="'.$phone.'"  where SRNO="'.$srno.'"');   

    header('Location:'.$page);
}
```

THe complete code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>List of users</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <?php
        $page='index.php';  

        mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("list") or die (mysql_error());

        if (empty($_POST) === false)
        {

            $fname= $_POST['fname'];
            $lname= $_POST['lname'];
            $srno=  $_POST['SRNO'];
            $address=$_POST['address'];
            $comments=$_POST['comments'];
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $phone=$_POST['phone'];
            echo 'Hello'.$address;          
            mysql_query('update names set fname="'.$fname.'", lname="'.$lname.'", address="'.$address.'", comments="'.$comments.'", email="'.$email.'", phone="'.$phone.'"  where SRNO="'.$srno.'"');   

            header('Location:'.$page);
        }


        if(isset($_GET['edit']))
        {
            $getedit=mysql_query('SELECT SRNO, fname, lname, phone, email, address, comments from names where SRNO='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['edit']));

            echo '<table border=0>';
            while ($get_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($getedit))
                {
                    echo '<form method="POST" action="">';

                    echo '<tr><td>Sr.No:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['SRNO'].' name="SRNO" readonly="readonly"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['fname'].' name="fname"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['lname'].' name="lname"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Phone No:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['phone'].' name="phone"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>E-mail address:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['email'].' name="email"</td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Address:</td><td><textarea rows=4>'.$get_row['address'].'</textarea></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Comments:</td><td><textarea rows=4>'.$get_row['comments'].'</textarea></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="save"></td><td></td></tr>';
                    echo '</form>';                                 
                }
            echo '</table>';

        }

        $get=mysql_query('SELECT  SRNO, fname, lname, email, phone, address, comments from names ORDER BY SRNO ASC');

        if (mysql_num_rows($get)==0)
        {
            echo 'There are no entries';
        }
            else
        {
            echo '<table border=0 cellspacing=25 cellpadding=1>';
            echo'<tr><th>Sr. No</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Phone No</th><th>E-mail</th><th>Address</th><th>Comments!!</th><th>Modify</th></tr>';      
            while($get_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
                {
                    echo '<tr><td>'.$get_row['SRNO'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['fname'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['lname'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['phone'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['email'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['address'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['comments'].'</td><td><a href="index.php?edit='.$get_row['SRNO'].'">Edit</a></td></tr>';

                }
            echo '</table>';
        }       
    ?>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You code is vulnerable to SQL injection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add name tags to your textarea code;

```
echo '<tr><td>Address:</td><td><textarea rows=4 name="address">'.$get_row['address'].'</textarea></td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your textarea doesn't have a name attribute. It should be :

```
echo '<tr><td>Address:</td><td><textarea name="address" rows=4>'.$get_row['address'].'</textarea></td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td >Comments:</td><td><textarea rows=4 name="comments">'.$get_row['comments'].'</textarea></td></tr>';
```

Hope this helps